# FutureWarning error when calculating accuracy of a Word2Vec model

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to compute the accuracy of a Word2Vec model. This is my code:

```
import gensim

vectors = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load("cbow_vectors.kv", mmap='r')

questions = "questions-words.txt"

analogy_scores = vectors.accuracy(questions, restrict_vocab=30000, case_insensitive=True)
```

I get the following error:

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py:737:
>   FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from
>   `int` to `np.signedinteger` is deprecated. In future, it will be
>   treated as `np.int32 == np.dtype(int).type`.   if
>   np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int):

and then nothing happens :(
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is not an error just a warning from gensim package that you can ignore. Does program ends or you kill it manually? if you are not killing it manually then let it continue to run because when you train a model it takes some time to learn so let it continue

Comment: I’m not killing it manually, it just displays that warning and then the command input line comes back for me to type something else. that’s why i assumed it was this warning preventing it from running

Comment: Just realised i’m completely stupid and just forgot to write print(analogy_scores). But thank you for your help.